# hide one particular field in search layout for normal users sugarcrm 6.5.18

Tags: sugarcrm

Need to hide one particular field in search layout for normal user, if admin logins no need to hide that particular filed in search lay outs..

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate following plugin for field level access control:

[SugarCRM Field Level Access Control](https://store.biztechconsultancy.com/sugarcrm-field-level-access-control.htm)

Comment: I was not given clarity of my field, 
my field source is non-db, i want this filed to hide for normal users in search layouts, with  https://store.biztechconsultancy.com/sugarcrm-field-level-access-control.htm we can make hide normal fields to the users if im not wrong..
thanks
naren